# Unnecessary (?) ReadOnly fields in Interfaces

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, dependency-injection

Under the context of dependency injection - that is, an interface has mostly one implementation - I took the habit of exposing via the Interface a bunch of fields which are never called by the consumer classes. These fields reflect a high-level implementation strategy; I decided to expose them via my interfaces because I feel it helps to understand how the abstraction works - or let's say what is expected from that abstraction - not in terms of detailed implementation, but in terms of high-level principles and why the object/interface was needed in the first place.

For example, I have an interface `IEncrypter` which encrypts strings. The idea behind this interface is to be able to choose which encryption algorithm to use. So the implementation class takes an algorithm abstraction `IEncryptionAlgo` in its constructor, and stores it as a ReadOnly field: `ThisEncryptionAlgo As IEncryptionAlgo`. Then when I call `Encrypt(Message)`, it calls `ThisEncryptionAlgo.Encrypt(Message)`.

Strictly speaking, the interface does not need to expose `ThisEncryptionAlgo`, and exposing the `Byte() Encrypt(Message As String)` function alone is sufficient for the consumer. However, I feel that having the Interface exposing `ThisEncryptionAlgo` (as a ReadOnly) has some advantages:

- You help developers to understand the spirit behind the interface, which is useful both when implementing and when consuming.
- You make debugging easier as you can quickly inspect the property directly from the interface.
- Error logging and tracing might be easier if you generate a report based on the interface properties.

I believe it is ok because the main purpose of having this as an interface rather than a concrete class is to allow dependency injection and unit testing of the consumers, not to add a true layer of abstraction. Having said that, it also defeats the principle that interfaces should disregard any implementation details.

What is your opinion? Should I remove `ThisEncryptionAlgo` from my interface?

---

### Full Example

```
Interface IEncryptionAlgo

    Function Encrypt(Input As Byte()) As Byte()

    Function Decrypt(Input As Byte()) As Byte()

End Interface


Interface ICheckSumAlgo

    Function GetHashSum(Input As Byte()) As Byte()

    ReadOnly Property HashLength As Integer

End Interface


Interface IEncrypter

    ReadOnly Property ThisEncryptionAlgo As IEncryptionAlgo

    ReadOnly Property ThisCheckSumAlgo As ICheckSumAlgo

    Function Encrypt(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function Decrypt(Cypher As Byte()) As String

    Function EncryptWihCheckSum(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function DecryptWithCheckSum(SumAndCypher As Byte()) As String

End Interface


Class Encrypter
    Implements IEncrypter


    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Sub New(Algo As IEncryptionAlgo, CheckSum As ICheckSumAlgo)
        Me.ThisEncryptionAlgo = Algo
        Me.ThisCheckSumAlgo = CheckSum
    End Sub


    Public ReadOnly Property ThisEncryptionAlgo As IEncryptionAlgo Implements IEncrypter.ThisEncryptionAlgo

    Public ReadOnly Property ThisCheckSumAlgo As ICheckSumAlgo Implements IEncrypter.ThisCheckSumAlgo


    Public Function Encrypt(Message As String) As Byte() Implements IEncrypter.Encrypt

        Dim MessageBytes As Byte() = Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Message)

        Dim Cypher As Byte() = Me.ThisEncryptionAlgo.Encrypt(MessageBytes)
        Return Cypher

    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(Cypher() As Byte) As String Implements IEncrypter.Decrypt

        Dim MessageBytes As Byte() = Me.ThisEncryptionAlgo.Decrypt(Cypher)

        Dim Message As String = Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(MessageBytes)
        Return Message

    End Function


    Public Function EncryptWihCheckSum(Message As String) As Byte() Implements IEncrypter.EncryptWihCheckSum

        Dim Cypher As Byte() = Encrypt(Message)
        Dim CypherSum As Byte() = Me.ThisCheckSumAlgo.GetHashSum(Cypher)

        Dim SumAndCypher As Byte() = CypherSum.Concat(Cypher).ToArray
        Return SumAndCypher

    End Function

    Public Function DecryptWithCheckSum(SumAndCypher() As Byte) As String Implements IEncrypter.DecryptWithCheckSum

        Dim Cypher As Byte() = SumAndCypher.Skip(Me.ThisCheckSumAlgo.HashLength).ToArray
        Dim ExpectedCypherSum As Byte() = SumAndCypher.Take(Me.ThisCheckSumAlgo.HashLength).ToArray
        Dim CurrentCypherSum As Byte() = Me.ThisCheckSumAlgo.GetHashSum(Cypher)

        If Not CurrentCypherSum.SequenceEqual(ExpectedCypherSum) Then Throw New ArgumentException("Check sum failed.", NameOf(SumAndCypher))

        Dim Message As String = Decrypt(Cypher)
        Return Message

    End Function


End Class

Class ServicesFactory
    Implements IServicesFactory

    Function NewEncrypter() As IEncrypter Implements IServicesFactory
        Return New Encrypter(My.AppSettings.GetDefaultAlgo, My.AppSettings.GetDefaultCheckSum)
    End Function

End Class


Class ConsummerClass

    Private ReadOnly Property MainFactory As IServicesFactory

    Private Sub New
    End Sub

    Sub New(MainFactory as IServicesFactory)
        Me.MainFactory=MainFactory
    End Sub

    Sub Main()

        Dim MyMessage As String = InputBox("Write something")

        Dim Encrypter As IEncrypter = Me.MainFactory.NewEncrypter
        Dim EncryptedMessage As Byte() = Encrypter.Encrypt(MyMessage)

        WebClient.SendPost(Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedMessage))

    End Sub

End Class
```

As one can see, it is "by design" that `IEncrypter` holds a field which refers to the algo object to use. If one wants to use a different algo, they may implement `IEncryptionAlgo` and inject it via the `ServicesFactory`. Under such context, `ThisEncryptionAlgo` is not needed by the consumer class, but having it exposed via the `IEncrypter` interface ensures any implementation of the later fits the overall architecture. At least, that is what I intuitively feel, but I'd like to challenge this.

Comment: My question might as well apply to concrete classes: Should I make `ThisEncryptionAlgo` private?

Comment: You make multiple claims about interfaces which are very dubious, such as "an interface has mostly one implementation" or "having that interface is to allow dependency injection and unit testing, not to add a true layer of abstraction". You conflate interfaces and dependency injection. An interface _is_ an abstraction, and you shouldn't create one if you don't need the abstraction! The entire point is to decouple the client of your abstraction from its actual implementation.

Comment: There are different levels of abstraction. In my example, you may distinguish the encryption algo, from who chose which algo to use, and from how it was offered to choose an algo. The consummer does not care which algo was choosen, but exposing which algo was choosen indicates the fields exposed by that same object are tight to this choice. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Ama Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it more clear what you mean.

Comment: @ama why make people ask which algo was chosen? Let them inject a logger and talk to them through that if they care so much.

Comment: @xtratic I have just added an example. I wanted to avoid diving into code, but it looks like this will definitely clarify the question as it appears to be more subtle than I thought.

Comment: @candied_orange the purpose is not to allow people to choose, the purpose is to provide room for changes in the future, for example when an algo gets deprecated, you replace it with another algo in the factory.

Comment: @Ama wasn’t addressing choices or changes. Was saying we debuggers like trace logs.

Comment: The larger your public API, the harder you might make it changable in the future.  Don't require things not strictly needed.

Comment: @xtratic This isn't SE, this is softwareengineering; we don't require MCVEs here, this exchange is for whiteboard designing things.

Comment: "the purpose is not to allow people to choose, the purpose is to provide room for changes in the future"  YAGNI.

Comment: Your full example is missing the most important code: the test that makes use of these read only fields that might convince anyone that doing this was worth it.

Comment: @Andy No, we don't require MCVEs here, but they certainly help in understanding the question and to get everyone on the same page so we can have a meaningful discussion.

Comment: @xtratic And we have comments to ask for clarifications as well.  MCVEs aren't the only way to clarify a question.

Comment: @Andy Of course they aren't the *only* way, I never said they were.. I simply find them very useful when trying to help the asker: they provide a more clear context and a solid base for discussion, or further clarifying questions if needed, and allow comments or answers to clearly reference the provided code (*as was done with the accepted answer to this question*).

Comment: @Andy I'll be frank: To me, it looks like you're trying to play "greater-than-thou" or perhaps "gatekeeper", especially in the phrasing of your comment ("This isn't SE, this is..."), and I don't appreciate it.. I know the purpose of SE and I know what helps me to provide better answers to questions, which is what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like that you are thinking about knowledge management, which to me is very important, and I'm not completely against small compromises in architectural elegance if they improve the productivity of your development team.

That being said, I believe your readonly fields connote something very different about the class.

Let's examine the two options.

```
Interface IEncrypter

    Function Encrypt(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function Decrypt(Cypher As Byte()) As String

    Function EncryptWihCheckSum(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function DecryptWithCheckSum(SumAndCypher As Byte()) As String

End Interface
```

The above is a black box that is capable of encrypting and decrypting strings. If that is all your application needs, that is all you need to specify in the interface that is being injected.

```
Interface IEncrypter

    ReadOnly Property ThisEncryptionAlgo As IEncryptionAlgo

    ReadOnly Property ThisCheckSumAlgo As ICheckSumAlgo

    Function Encrypt(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function Decrypt(Cypher As Byte()) As String

    Function EncryptWihCheckSum(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function DecryptWithCheckSum(SumAndCypher As Byte()) As String

End Interface
```

The above is not just an encryptor and decryptor. It is a ***helper class*** and a ***container*** for an algorithm. This is a very different animal. Even though it provides all the abilities of your encryptor, its role is no longer to *hide* the implementation from the caller but to assist with calling yet another interface.

The latter locks you into more design decisions. For example, it precludes a null encryption scheme (which would have no algorithm) and it precludes encryption schemes that may utilize more than one algorithm (e.g. RSA + AES, which you might use for longer messages that require public key cryptography).

If you just want an encryptor and not a helper, but you want to expose a hint about the algorithm for debugging or logging purposes, you might consider exposing the hint as a string instead.

```
Interface IEncrypter

    ReadOnly Property EncryptionMethod As String

    Function Encrypt(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function Decrypt(Cypher As Byte()) As String

    Function EncryptWihCheckSum(Message As String) As Byte()

    Function DecryptWithCheckSum(SumAndCypher As Byte()) As String

End Interface
```

That way you aren't locked into using exactly one algorithm object, and you still have a way to meet your debugging and knowledge management needs.

Comment: Your suggestion to expose the "knowledge" fields via a string is a compromise I really like. However, as I commented somewhere else, nothing stops you from implementing RSA+AES together, or to use a null encryption: just use RSA+AES to implement *together* IEncryptionAlgo and you're good.

Answer (score 8):

Yes remove it.

You prevent someone implementing an encryptor without implementing an Algo effectively tightly coupling your classes.

You don't need an interface to do unit testing or dependency injection. DI and unit testing require abstraction.

Addendum for full code

Neither the service factory or the consuming code use the extra read only properties, They only require an:

```
IEncryptor
    byte[] Encrypt(string)
```

Now some people would argue that you should make interfaces as small as possible, splitting up the decryption etc. I wouldn't go that far, but its a matter of taste.

However, it sounds like the only thing that you expect to call the read only fields is your unit tests to check that the servicefactory returns correctly built objects.

There are lots of ways you can do this without exposing the value as a property, and I would argue it doesn't really help with the tests at all, since I could implement an Encryptor which exposes a different algorithm to the one it actually uses.

This is better achieved by simply encrypting a string and comparing the result to a known values encrypted with the expected algorithm.

Comment: The main purpose of the class is to allow for choosing an algo (kind of a strategy pattern I guess?), not to implement an algo. Which is why in a sense exposing the choosen algo does not feel incredibly awful to me. (yet the consumer does not care which algo was chosen).
How would you unit test the consumer of this interface, if it was not an interface?

Comment: if its readonly and a construction parameter how does the class allow you to choose it

Comment: «The main purpose of the class is to allow for choosing an algo» — Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why can't you just pass an algo class or instance? If you just unify an interface to encrypt bytes, just expose `.Encrypt()`.

Comment: A factory creates the `Encrypter` object and passes the algo through the constructor. Then the instance of the `Encrypter` is passed to any consumer class.
This is just an example; another one could be a `SendToServerService` object which takes a `URL` in the constructor, and exposes various methods such as `SendSomething`, `SendSomethingElse`, etc. Should `ISendToServer` expose a ReadOnly `DestinationUrl`.

Comment: why not just have the factory return an IAlgo? is the essential question. your code is never going to check the factory returned the correct algorthim, your tests should check that the encryption result matches a known correct value encrypted with the expected algorithim

Comment: @Ama Is there a good reason to have IEncrypter be an interface? If the answer is not really, then you could just turn the IEncrypter interface into a concrete class that takes an IEncryptionAlgo and an ICheckSumAlgo as dependencies, turning the whole thing into a Strategy pattern - this would also communicate your intent clearly.

Comment: Strategy pattern is indeed what I am aiming for, and the reason I feel I should expose `IEncryptionAlgo` and `ICheckSumAlgo` is indeed to communicate a feel of the pattern. The only reason I believe I need an `Encrypter` as interface is so that I can unit test the consumer class (by injecting a different `ServicesFactory`, which creates a fake `IEncrypter`)

Comment: @Ama, what would your fake `IEncrypter` put in its `ThisEncryptionAlgo` property? If it is part of the interface, then the client can depend on it and actually do something like `Encrypter.ThisEncryptionAlgo.Encrypt(…)`.

Comment: `IEncrypter` is an interface so that I can unit test the consumer, not the encryption itself. So the fake `IEncrypter` would be implemented by an algo which does not encrypt (just converts `string` to `byte()`), and the value of the `ThisEncryptionAlgo` field would be null as it does not matter. As i mentioned, this field is **never** used - not event in unit testing - it is just here to provide some "knowledge" and guide the developers.

Answer (score 5):

I'm used to think that an *interface* only defines methods and constants. We can, of course, suppose that for "read-only fields" your interface are methods that return constant values.

The point of an interface if to define, well, an interface, but allow any reasonable implementation.

If a reasonable implementation would need full access to an encryption algorithm anyway, then exposing `GetEncryptionAlgo()` (or passing it as a parameter to an interface method) is ok.

If `ThisEncryptionAlgo.Encrypt` is *strictly sufficient* for the purposes of your interface, then exposing the rest is not a good idea, in my eys.

What you call the "spirit" seems to be your hunch of a possible implementation. This *limits* possible implementations. E.g. if you have a completely different encryption library then you are used to, it's easy t expose via the interface that only needs `.Encrypt`, and hard, or impossible, in your interface.

Ironically, it becomes *harder* to mock the encryption provider for testing of a class implementing that interface: you need to mock more, and have an easier time to mock it incorrectly.

In general, I'd suggest to expose *only the strict minimum* of methods in an interface. The simpler it is, the lower the chance of implementing it incorrectly.

If you want to expose more, consider an extended interface that augments your minimal interface with specific implementation conveniences:

```cs
interface Stream<T> {  // Minimal.
  T Read();
  Boolean HasMore();
}

interface SeekableStream<T> : Stream<T> {
  long GetPosition();
  void Seek(long);
}

class File<T> : SeekableStream<T> { // Still acceptable anywhere a Stream goes.
... 
}
```

Comment: By "spirit", I guess I meant architecture: I am in a case where exposing the indeed constant field is not adding constraints to the implementation because it is expected to be done that way. If an algorithm which does not implement `IAlgo` is required, then it should implement `IAlgo`, not `IEncrypter`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be very cautious about adding such "extra" methods to your interface.

An interface should be very clear about its responsibility.

Is `IEncrypter` truly responsible to tell you about an `IEncryptionAlgo` or `ICheckSumAlgo`? I think it should only `Encrypt` and `Decrypt`. By adding extra methods you are imposing more requirements/constraints on the implementations.

What about if you wanted a non-encrypting `IEncrypter` that just lets the bytes pass through, what would you return for `ThisEncryptionAlgo`? You might return `null` or a blank `IEncryptionAlgo` but that might cause an `NPE` in the caller or just push your problems farther down the line.

You shouldn't have exposed it in the first place, the details of the Encrypter should not be exposed. Once an interface shares something, users of that interface could make a connection to it and such connections require maintenance and are hard to break.

If you're sharing the `IEncryptionAlgo` and `ICheckSumAlgo` so that you can log about them then, rather than returning those implementation details, you could instead just make the `GetEncrypterInfo As String` a part of your interface and any implementer could fulfill that much more easily.

Comment: Your comment on logging is interesting. Regarding the non-encrypting IEncrypter, I would actually implement an `IEncryptionAlgo` which would implement the Enrypt/Decrypt methods by returning the bytes as they are.